# Could not add Object List in Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a Java DTO object designed like this:

```
Product
|__ name
|__ List<ClientDTO> clients
```

I give my DTO product to Jasper like this :

```
JRDataSource datasource= new JRBeanArrayDataSource(new Product[]{product});
```

With Jaspersoft studio, I can easily display the Field name but I can't find a method to display the client list.

I tried using the element List available in the palette but it requires a Dataset. Alright, I created a clientDataset. But how can I feed the clientDataset with my clients List?

Answer (score 1):

1) In the main report, create DataSet

2) From Palette, add a List Element the report

3) A window is opened, select your DataSet

4) Double click on the List element. In the DataSet menu, fill in "Use JRDataSource Expression" with `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{customers})`

5) Go back to your DataSet setup to add the Fields

6) Double Click on the list and drag and drop the fields in it

That's it !

Source code generated :

```
<componentElement>
            <reportElement x="110" y="4" width="444" height="20" uuid="118abb83-369d-408b-a3bc-194b978d3fab"/>
            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="customersDataSet" uuid="ce33a9a6-0aaf-4df0-abb7-fc52b0553191">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{customers})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:listContents height="20" width="444">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20" uuid="a65f7a8f-1530-4657-ac3d-a053ea18cb14"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{civilite}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="120" height="20" uuid="5f85470a-8c28-4550-aac8-e414ff64fe90"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="150" y="0" width="140" height="20" uuid="6a8c4e04-4278-4595-845f-67be590d9210"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </jr:listContents>
            </jr:list>
</componentElement>



<subDataset name="customersDataSet" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="10331e47-e08a-42d9-8733-bcf103ea7aed">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="civilite" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String"/>
</subDataset>
```